# Wordpress Author Page Custom Order

Tags: arrays, wordpress, sorting

I have the following code to call only the "authors" from my WordPress for an author page, and need to be able to list them in a custom order.

```
// Get users
$all_users = get_users('role=author');
$allowed_users = array();
foreach ( $all_users as $user ):
    $wp_user = new WP_User($user->ID);
    if ( !in_array( 'subscriber', $wp_user->roles ) ):
        array_push($allowed_users, $user);
    endif;

endforeach;

// Display users    
foreach ($allowed_users as $user)
{ ?>
```

... code to display author info.

I need to list the authors in the order of author id: 6,2,5,4,1. This is for a radio station website so I want to list the "authors" in the same order they're on the air.

Comment: Just to clarify: Are you trying to grab all Users, but list all users with IDs of 6,2,5,4,1 first followed by the rest? Or only the Users with IDs of 6,2,5,4,1?

Comment: I'm grabbing all users that are "author" types (which are just those numbers for now), and then want to list in that order. If it's easier to grab just those author IDs on the page I'm fine with that. I can update the code when I add "authors" as they won't change often. I'm obviously a novice and just trying to customize the theme I picked up. Thanks so much for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's really no custom ordering option that will allow you to define a specific order by ID, but there are ways around it. Something like this should get you started:

```
<?php
$primary_authors = array(6,2,5,4,1);
$other_authors = new WP_User_Query(array(
    'role'=>'Author',
    'exclude'=>$primary_authors
));
$authors = array();
foreach($primary_authors as $uid) $authors[] = new WP_User($uid);
foreach($other_authors->results as $user) $authors[] = $user;
?>
```

What this does is define a very specific order of user IDs you would like to show up first. Then, a second query is made that grabs the rest of the users with a role of Author, excluding the ones defined in $primary_authors.

We iterate through the $primary_authors array first, and push a new WP_User instance to the $authors array, and then grab the rest of the authors in a second loop if any exist.

This way, if you create any new Authors they will still be included, but you can pick and choose the ones you would like to be weighted by adding them to the $primary_authors array.

Comment: Worked perfectly. Thank you SO much!